# Xcode 7.3 - Unknown class <MealViewController> in Interface Builder file

Tags: ios, xcode, class, xcode7.3

I'm a beginner developer and I'm following the [Getting Started](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH2-SW1) apple tutorial to learn the basics.

This "unknown class" has appeared in a few other threads but none of the answers seemed to fix the problem this time. I checked all the references to class and the storyboard source code as well as the project builder/compile sources. Keeps failing.

The breakpoint appears in this part of the code at the custom class MealTableViewController.swift

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {           
        if segue.identifier == "ShowDetail" {

            let mealDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! MealViewController

            if let selectedMealCell = sender as? MealTableViewCell {

                let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(selectedMealCell)!
                let selectedMeal = meals[indexPath.row]
                mealDetailViewController.meal = selectedMeal
            }

        }

        else if segue.identifier == "AddItem" {

            print("Adding new meal.")
        }
    }
```

The problem occurs when clicking any cell in the table view, so I have the impression it might have to do with the segue. But i've checked everything against the tutorial and see no difference.

I've uploaded the entire project [here](https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/7c2345238f74fc508e7d182bbace33ad20160602012345/3d2d0e0be2e723bcb126101ac877636120160602012345/2699d4). I'm trying to upload it as a git repo but that's another thing I have to learn.

Any help is appreciated, I've run out of options on what to test heer.

Comment: You have set the custom class for the navigation item in the new meal scene to `MealViewController` - clear this out and let it default to `UINavigationItem`

Comment: @Paulw11 I did check the id inspector on both navigation controllers and the classes were UINavigationController for both of them... This (http://imgur.com/XqYgbvj) is the info I see when I click the meal scene navigation controller. Should I check this someplace else?

Comment: Not the navigation controllers, the navigation item.  The grey box with the blue "<" named "New Meal"; You can right click on your storyboard and select open as source and then do a find for MealViewController - this is what I did

Comment: @Paulw11 okay, i just checked this and in the storyboard the new meal item shows the original class, if i'm selecting it correctly (http://imgur.com/Kk7ILb1). i checked the storyboard source, and there it seems that the new meal item is inside the mealviewcontroller class (http://imgur.com/Xc215ZT) is this what i should be looking for?

Comment: Yes, that looks correct now

Comment: @Paulw11 when clicking the tableviewcell the app is still crashing, the only difference is the message about the class doesnt show up in the console any longer. but a breakpoint continues to show up in the tableviewcontroller (http://imgur.com/dcOhUtT)

Comment: That's because you have set a breakpoint - the blue arrow in the margin.  Click it to turn it off or drag it out to get rid of it altogether

Comment: pretty basic mistakes. working perfectly now. thank you!